# Does returning from onStopCommand end the Android service?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

The Android documentation about services says: "Another application component can start a service and it will continue to run in the background even if the user switches to another application."

Let's suppose the Android service spawns a thread or AsyncTask in onStartCommand:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
//asyncrhonous call-1
new SomeAsyncTask().execute();
//asynchronous call-2
new Thread(new Runnable(){//some runnable}).start();
//shouldn't service terminate here?
return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

In the code above, the `onStartCommand` return statement is encountered immediately since the two statements before it are asynchronous. Shouldn't the service terminate before the threads spawned here end their execution? What if they are non-daemon?

Furthermore, as the services (slightly confused about the IntentService) execute on the UI thread, we need to perform network operations in separate a thread. Hence one may often need to create asynctasks or different threads. Can anyone help me in understanding a service's execution and if a service "continues to run in the background"? Then, after returning from onStartCommand, what does it "run"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my doubt is that shouldn't the service terminate before the threads spawned here end their execution

No. `onStopCommand()` returning does not indicate that the service is being destroyed.

> if a service "continue to run in the background",then after returning from onStartCommand, what does it "run"?

Nothing, by default. It just sits there, taking up memory, and being a general nuisance to the user.

If you start a service, you need to have a clear plan for when and how that service will stop. A service is stopped either by itself calling `stopSelf()` or by somebody else calling `stopService()`.

Comment: "A service is stopped either by itself calling stopSelf() or by somebody else calling stopService()." Does stopping it this way terminates running non-daemon threads which it created also?

Comment: @rahulserver: That depends on who "it" is. Threads created by the Android framework code are the responsibility of the Android framework code, so the background thread created by an `IntentService` will be stopped when the `IntentService` is stopped. Thread created by *you* are *your* responsibility -- Android's framework code does not know anything about them.

Comment: "the background thread created by an IntentService" by this do you mean the thread which we have "explicitly" coded in one of the IntentService lifecycle methods or created implicitly by android os(the worker thread)?

Comment: @rahulserver: "do you mean the thread which we have "explicitly" coded in one of the IntentService lifecycle methods" -- that is not a proper use of `IntentService`. "or created implicitly by android os(the worker thread)" -- I mean the one created by the Google-employed author of the `IntentService` class that is part of the Android framework. From your perspective as an app developer, you could say that it is "created implicitly", insofar as you are probably not the Google employee who wrote `IntentService` itself.

Comment: Actually my original question concerns Services in general. However I thank you for pointing out:"that is not a proper use of IntentService". I hav already upvoted for this superb answer. Shall I conclude that in case of non-daemon threads, we need to kill then ourselves?

Comment: @rahulserver: If you fork the thread, you need to clean it up. I have not tried `setDaemon()` on Android, and its described behavior seems antithetical to the Android process model and proper use of services. Leaving a thread running after the component that created it is destroyed represents a leak. Moreover, it represents an unreliable scenario, as the process can be terminated regardless of the existence of your own leaked threads, daemon or otherwise.

Comment: Well I think the issue of daemon threads is a question on its own.I would ask it in another post as I want more opinions.As for this question, I am considering it as solved. Thank you very much!!

Comment: could you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529988/has-javamail-deprecated-for-android ?